# MultiLayer Perceptron not working for regression problem, what could I try?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, python, keras

I am trying to learn the inverse kinematics of a robotic manipulator. To do that I have a simulator with which I acquired data.

My dataset is composed of positions in X, Y and Z and actuator variables (6 of them). That represents around 310 000 rows. Therefore, the inputs of my NN are the positions (3 inputs) and the outputs the actuator variables (6 outputs).

Just before (when my dataset were much simpler, 3 outputs only) I managed to obtain good results with a MLP. However, now that the dataset is much more complicated, I did not manage to obtain a similar result.

Being a beginner in deep learning, my question would be, what else could I try to obtain a better results than the one using MLP ?

First here is the code I used for the simpler case where I achieve a good result :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
    from joblib import dump, load
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    
    data = np.genfromtxt('dataprocess.csv', delimiter=',')
    
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    data[1:,[4,5,6,7,8,9]] = scaler.fit_transform(data[1:,[4,5,6,7,8,9]])
    
    
    trainset, testset = train_test_split(data[1:, [4,5,6,7,8,9]], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    
    
    
    X_train = trainset[:,[3, 4, 5]]
    X_test = testset[:,[3, 4, 5]]
    
    Y_train = trainset[:,[0, 1, 2]]
    Y_test = testset[:,[0, 1, 2]]
    print("Y train min", Y_train.min())
    print("Y train max", Y_train.max())
    
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,))  # Entrée : x, y, z
    hidden_layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l1_l2')(input_layer)  # Couche intermédiaire
    hidden_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l1_l2')(hidden_layer1)  # Couche intermédiaire
    hidden_layer3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l1_l2')(hidden_layer2)  # Couche intermédiaire
    hidden_layer4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l1_l2')(hidden_layer3)  # Couche intermédiaire
    output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)(hidden_layer4)  # Sortie : variables d'actionnement
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
    
    
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    
    History = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), epochs=150, batch_size=512, verbose=2, shuffle = True)
    print("history loss ", History.history['loss'])
    
    
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Test accuracy:", accuracy)
    print("Test loss:", loss)
    
    model.save_weights('modele_poids.h5')
    
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(History.history['loss'], linestyle='-', label='train loss')
    plt.plot(History.history['val_loss'], linestyle='-', label='test loss')
    plt.legend()
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(History.history['accuracy'], label='train score')
    plt.plot(History.history['val_accuracy'], label='test score')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

That gave my good results when I have 3 outputs but now that I have 6 of them it is no longer the case. Even if I add more neurons or more layers.

Moreover, here is what my dataset looks like (I removed some unused columns, that is normal if the index doens't match the dataset).

[image: data]

Comment: a big enough (your case falls in here) MLP is very likely powerful enough for your dataset, because at most it can learn by heart your data, so probably you messed up something (possibly in the data processing or the training)

Comment: Hi! You can better ask these kinds of questions on the data science stack exchange